# Problem with unlocking my lenovo tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, lenovo, tablet

I have a problem with my tablet that I bought recetly.

I'm not a fan of Android so I wanted to run it with Ubuntu OS.

I followed every step in [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) page.

But exactly when I try to unlock the device in order to install Ubuntu, the tablet stuck in the fastboot mode.

How should I proceed.